# Adding java folders to android studio project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, directory

Started working on my first project using **Android Studio instead of Eclipse ADT**.
I would like to add sub folders to contain java.classes in order to structure my app but are unable to obtain references to them in my activity

structure is (with app name replaced)

```
src/main/[MyCompany]/[myAppName]/model/user.java
```

and

```
src/main/[MyCompany]/[myAppName]/helperClasses/SQLiteHelper.java
```

however I am unable to reference them either directly in code or by import, and are forced to put them in the appName folder with the activity to reference them.

Is this simply a limitation in Android or is there a way to organize your project with folders better. I used the `new->folder-java` folder option to create folders

Answer (score 47):

IntelliJIdea mixes packages and directories.

So, right click on the java folder, click new - 'Package', then add your directory.

Comment: Can u please suggest something here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39542522/issue-while-creating-the-new-package-inside-package-in-android-studio

Answer (score 15):

In my case I wanted a mock package with java folder:

1. First step you have to put project mode:

[image]

2. Click right button, new, Directory, in my case "mock".
3. Click right button, new, Folder, Java Folder:

[image]

4. Click in checkbock "change folder location" and put your path,
   in my case "src/mock/java":

[image]

5. The solution is this:

[image]

Comment: Instead of adding a folder, right click on the current package (com.example.coolapp) and select New → Package.  Type the name for the subfolder, and a new package subfolder will be created beneath `com.example.coolapp`.  In Java, each subfolder is considered a new package.  Doing it this way will make sure that Java classes created in the subfolder or moved between folders will function correctly (Android Studio will auto-update import statements and package names so they function correctly).

Answer (score 1):

Try this path : `src/main/java/[MyCompany]/[myAppName]/...`
`src/main/java/` is default **source directory** in Android Studio

OR

if you don't want to change your directory structure.
you have to modify your `build.gradle`to change source directory.

something like: (this example is for ADT project)

```
android {

    ...

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: It would appear that due to my unfamiliarity with AndroidStudio what you propose is essentially what I've got.
src/main/java/companyName.AppName/model/user.Java
which doesn't help, unless I put user.java directly into the companyName.AppName folder. I'm curious if it's even supposed to be possible to put java files into sub folders for android projects?

Sorry about the long delay, Christmas and all that...

Comment: About 3 weeks ago, I thought that you want to import ADT project to AS project. So I answered like that. But now, I read again your question, I have found misunderstood your question. sorry, my fault.
I think ```new->folder-java``` was the problem. In my guess, your project's build.gradle file has something like this: ```sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/[MyCompany]/[myAppName]'] } }```. check it out, then ease them and run 'sync with gradle'.
In general case, you don't have to create new folder-java.
just drag-and drop the folder at your project navigate view.

Comment: But he wants to change the dir structure. That is the question.