# Organizing files into groups in Android Project

Tags: android

How is it possible to organize my files into groups (folders) in Android Studio? For instance, under the main 'java' folder, I'd like to add file groups such as 'models', 'controllers', etc.

Comment: don't you read the `package` in java `http://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/packages-in-java/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, the best answers are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071293/android-project-how-best-to-organize-the-files). To manage your code, folder structure to make code clean and maintainable, [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Organizing-your-Source-Files) resource is a lot helpful. You can manage by :

`java
-Base package
--Model
--Controller
--Adapter
--Database
--Api`

And

`layout
-activity_
-fragment_
-adapter_`

Answer (score 0):

For Organizing java files in to group I will suggest to you can create Folder under the **src** in that your package

> right click on the java folder, click new - 'Package', then add your
>   directory.

For more information in step by step [Adding java folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539702/adding-java-folders-to-android-studio-project)  Aslo refer this documentation [enter link description here](http://Create/Add%20new%20Package%20inside%20src%20folder)

I think this will be help to solving your problem.