# Navigating through imports in Eclipse without project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

[image]I got my hands onto an Android project that was decompiled from `.apk` into an obfuscated version of a Java project (has the google, com folders and what not). I want to study the code, but it is hard, because all the paths look like `a.a.a.a.b().c();`

Is it possible to set up Eclipse, or any other IDE to accept the folder with all the `.java` classes and treat it as a project so when I click on the import or the object that was created using a different class, I would navigate to that class instead of manually searching for every file?

Comment: It appears that the project owners explicitly do not want you to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

> or any other IDE

Well in Android Studio. First I added a new folder with some java files and packages on my desktop, without any other files.

Then I managed to open it using Android Studio by simpling opening a folder as a project.

[image]

After that in my project structure tab, I selected `Project`.

[image]

And the files and subfolders appeared like they are present in the folder. Note that an `.idea` folder will be created by Android Studio when you open the project folder.

To actually navigate through the files you can create a Java project in Android Studio, then add a new sub-package, and open the folder containing the files.

[Adding java folders to android studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539702/adding-java-folders-to-android-studio-project)

Comment: I tried Android Studio and Intellij Java IDE - none of them register the structure and I can't navigate through project. Also added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Are you sure that the util file was decompiled correctly?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, but what is the util file? The structure is there. Like the com.app.data.ac import exists and I can navigate to it manually. I hope I understood your question.

Comment: Yes you understood correctly, but I mean, is the data.ac a full decompiled Java class?

Comment: Some are, some are not. Like the file is there and when I open it just has "null" inside. But others are true .java classes with no encoding errors.

Comment: I tried that - added an empty project, created a new package and then pasted all folders inside the package. It still can't find any references. It is weird how this will work, because the imports stayed the same relative to the com package. Not to root, right?

Comment: Yes it's very weird they should change with it. Tomorrow I will try to do the same.

Comment: Don't feel obligated =) You helped me at least get on the right track. But if you do - I will be greatful